# Multi-platform Java KeyStore

Tags: java, arm, keystore

I have [implemented here](https://github.com/triceo/robozonky/blob/master/robozonky-app/src/main/java/com/github/triceo/robozonky/app/util/KeyStoreHandler.java) a very simple `KeyStore`, pretty basic. Uses `JCEKS` keystore with `PBE` (password-based encryption). And everything was just fine on my PC and on a Mac, until users of the app started running it on an ARM board.

I found out that the Oracle JRE 8 on ARM supports neither JCEKS, nor PBE. Digging deeper into this, I have obtained the following complete return of `Security.getProviders()` call on [my PC and on ARM](https://gist.github.com/triceo/49ba5f5fa3277c62a755025fc0e8cad0). Based on the differences between the two of them, I see no common approach to storing passwords in a Key Store. `SunJCE` provider, which implements all the interesting stuff, is simply missing on ARM.

I looked all over the internet and found many examples, most of which eventually hinge on the use of `PBE`, which is not present on ARM. Even BouncyCastle seems to require `PBE` for this use case. Furthermore, the algorithms that Oracle's Javadoc says are mandatory for every JRE, seem to be missing on Oracle's ARM Java, too.

Is there a truly multi-platform way of doing password storage inside a KeyStore? And if not, what other mechanism for (two-way) password storage would you recommend? I'm primarily looking for open-source solutions, preferrably under Apache Software License.

All the systems I have used in this exercise have a fairly recent build of Oracle Java 8, 1.8.0_101 or 102.

Comment: Have you looked at [Chilkat](https://www.chilkatsoft.com/java.asp#armLinuxDownloads)? It's commercial, but supports ARM.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I should have mentioned I'm looking for open-source solutions, preferrably under ASL. I'll update my question.

Comment: Did you try using the Bouncy Castle JCE implementation for JDK 1.3 with your JRE 8 for ARM? Worth a try, at least.

Comment: @Andreas, not sure what you mean - I have tried BouncyCastle, which (for the two-way use case) also seems to require the non-existent PBE. If there's some non-PBE two-way password encryption in there, I wasn't able to find it.

Comment: PBE (Password-Based Encryption) is part of JCE (Java Cryptography Extension). It is included in Java 1.4+, but was a standalone extension jar for Java 1.2 and Java 1.3. If you look at the [Bouncy Castle download page](https://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html), you'll see a column named "Clean room JCE and provider", which has a jar file for JDK 1.3 named `jce-jdk13-155.jar`. Try adding that to your JRE 8 for ARM `lib/ext` folder.